# .format code only displays the first letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason the console only displays the first letter of what the reader inputs.  Why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
print ('Welcome to MadLibs')
string1 = input('Noun')
string2 = input('Plural Noun')
string3 = input('Noun')
string4 = input('Place')
string5 = input('Adjective')
string6 = input('Noun')
string='Be kind to your {}-footed {} For a duck may be somebody\'s {}, Be kind to your {} in {} Where the weather is always {}. You may think that this is the {}, Well it is.'
print(string.format(*string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6))
```

Comment: Get rid of the * in front of string1.

Comment: That only gives me this error code:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: You have 7 `{}` in your string, but are only giving it 6 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an asterisk (*) at the very beginning of your format call that you need to remove:

```
print(string.format(string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6))
```

The asterisk is how you *unpack* arguments to a function, something you don't need in this case. You also have 7 placeholders in your string, but only pass 6 variables into the format call. If you're using Python 3.6 and later, you should use `f-strings` instead (they're really great):

```
print(f"Be kind to your {string1}-footed {string2} For a duck "
      f"may be somebody's {string3}, Be kind to your {string4} "
      f"in {string5} Where the weather is always {string6}. "
      f"You may think that this is the {string7}, Well it is.")
```

F-strings make this kind of error a lot harder to introduce.

Comment: Removing the * only gives me:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 0):

The `*` before `string1` spreads the elements of that string into separate arguments. So it's equivalent to:

```
print(string.format(string1[0], string1[1], string1[2], ...,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6))
```

See [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) for the meaning of `*` in function definitions and argument lists.

Get rid of that.

```
print(string.format(string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6))
```

But now you don't have enough strings for all the placeholders in the format string. You're missing the Noun for `Be kind to your {} in`. So it should be:

```
print ('Welcome to MadLibs')
string1 = input('Noun')
string2 = input('Plural Noun')
string3 = input('Noun')
string4 = input('Noun')
string5 = input('Place')
string6 = input('Adjective')
string7 = input('Noun')
string='Be kind to your {}-footed {} For a duck may be somebody\'s {}, Be kind to your {} in {} Where the weather is always {}. You may think that this is the {}, Well it is.'
print(string.format(string1,string2,string3,string4,string5,string6,string7))
```

Comment: Removing the * only gives me:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Your format string has 7 `{}` placeholders but you only provided 6 strings to fill them in.

Comment: You need another Noun before Place.